# terminal process failed to launch : Invalid starting directory, review your terminal.integrated.cwd setting

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, terminal, esp32, espressif-idf

I'm trying to work with the esp32s3. To do so I've dowloaded [the universal installer](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/esp-idf/?idf=4.4), then installed everything from the installer... Next I've dowloaded Visual studio code and installed the ESP-IDF extension + the Cmake and some more...
[All the extensions installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKMyB.png)

Then I picked one of the example projects (blink) and added it into my work repertory.
With the ESP-IDF you have a tool bar on the bottom so I used it to set-target esp32s3...

After that I tried to compile the project but I always have this error :

Executing task: cmake -G Ninja -DPYTHON_DEPS_CHECKED=1 -DESP_PLATFORM=1 ..

- The terminal process failed to launch: Invalid starting directory "O:\APPLICATIONS...\blink\cmake ", review your terminal.integrated.cwd setting.

I don't really now what I'm doing wrong here. Maybe some kind of path problems for the terminal?
To be clear I had tons of problems before so maybe one of my previous solutions has caused this error to appear.

Working with windows 10, universal online installer 2.16, ESP-IDF v1.5.0 and

VS Version: 1.71.2 (user setup)
Commit: 74b1f979648cc44d385a2286793c226e611f59e7
Date: 2022-09-14T21:03:37.738Z
Electron: 19.0.12
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
Sandboxed: No

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the issue by changing some CMake settings : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/880

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).